# C++ реализация call_once

Tags: c++, mutex, lock-free

Хочу разобраться в том, как работает std::call_once. И главное - lock-free ли он. [Здесь](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117468/stdonce-flag-and-stdcall-once-implementation) пытаются его реализовать с использованием мьютекса. Если call_once можно реализовать только с использованием мьютекса, какие проблемы могут возникнуть с этим кодом?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;
using my_once_flag = atomic<bool>;

void my_call_once(my_once_flag& flag, std::function<void()> foo) {
    bool expected = false;
    bool res = flag.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true,
                                            std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if(res)
        foo();
}
my_once_flag flag;
void printOnce() {
    my_call_once(flag, [](){
       cout << "test" << endl;
    });
}
int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i< 50; ++i){
            thread([](){
                printOnce();
            }).detach();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандарт не налагает ограничений на реализацию `std::call_once` поэтому, его реализация может быть как с блокировками, так и без(я не знаю, возможно ли такую реализацию придумать).

Что касается Вашей реализации: она просто неверна. Пусть у нас будет 2 потока, которые одновременно заходят в функцию и попадают на строчку: `flag.compare_exchange_strong` один из них выставит флаг, а другой уйдёт с полной уверенностью, что функция уже была вызвана. Но до вызова функции дело ещё вообще не дошло! Поэтому, в правильной реализации, на входе в `call_once` все потоки должны выстроиться в очередь, если кто-то уже начал выполнение функции.

Конечно, если бы функция была «чистой»(pure) можно было бы устроить спекулятивное выполнение, с принятием результата от того потока, что первым закончит её исполнение. Но стандарт не налагает никаких ограничений на функцию, которая может быть исполнена в `call_once`. Поэтому, в целом, я не вижу как можно её реализовать в неблокирующем виде.